# How to access the mediaURL from twilio since it is integrated with Api.ai?

Tags: twilio, mms, dialogflow-es

I am currently trying to figure out how to receive an mms message via a twilio chatbot. I can't figure out how to access the mediaURL from twilio since it is integrated with Api.ai -- anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this issue quite a bit - Facebook/Twilio do not pass long the image event to API.ai. If another person out there is trying to have api.ai reply to an image event - you have to build in a node.js layer between facebook/twilio and Api.ai to ensure that information gets passed along.

Answer (score 1):

API.AI retains information on the original request from each integration.  Using a webhook you should be able to get all the information on a request including the mediaURL.  API.AI webhook requests from integrations include a JSON object called `originalRequest` which should have the information you need.  The JSON from API.AI's webhook request to your server should have this form:

```
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "source": "twilio",
    "data": {
        ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The data attribute should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Quick question - @matthewayne, how do i get the request through Api.ai since the mms(message of a photo) doesnt send to api.ai or trigger an intent?